# response.set_cookie() vs response.cookies[] in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views, django-cookies

I could set the cookies with [response.set_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) and `response.cookies[]` as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    response = HttpResponse('Test')
    response.set_cookie('first_name', 'John') # Here
    response.cookies['last_name'] = 'Smith' # Here
    return response
```

[image]

Then, I could only delete `response.set_cookie()`'s cookie `first_name` rather than `response.cookies[]`'s cookie `last_name` with [response.delete_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie) as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    response = HttpResponse('Test')
    response.delete_cookie('first_name') # Deleted
    response.delete_cookie('last_name') # Undeleted
    return response
```

[image]

So, what is the difference between `response.set_cookie()` and `response.cookies[]` in Django?

Answer (score 2):

- [response.set_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) always sets a cookie with the global path `/` if not specifying a path as an argument as shown below. *I recommend to basically use it without specifying a path as an argument because it's simple and consistent always setting a cookie with the global path `/`.
- `response.cookies[]` sets a cookie with the current url's path which can be `/`, `/my_app1` or others depending as shown below. *I don't recommend to basically use it because it's not simple and consistent setting a cookie with the current url's path which is kind of random.

[image]

And, [response.delete_cookie()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie) deletes the cookie of the global path `/` if not specifying a path as an argument. So to delete `response.cookies[]`'s cookie `last_name`, you need to specify `/my_app1` as an argument as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    response = HttpResponse('Test')
    response.delete_cookie('first_name')
    response.delete_cookie('last_name', '/my_app1')
    return response                    # ↑ Here ↑
```

Then, both `response.set_cookie()`'s cookie `first_name` and `response.cookies[]`'s cookie `last_name` are deleted as shown below:

[image]